# Migrar MSSOAP.SoapClient30 de VB a c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net, vba

El tema es que estoy migrando un proyecto de VBA a C#, y en el camino me encontre con:

`Set SoapClient = CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30") 'Objeto Web Service Soap
SoapClient.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True`

así que comencé a improvisar algo asi:

`MSSOAPLib30.SoapClient30 SoapClient = new MSSOAPLib30.SoapClient30();
SoapClient.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = true;`

> Pero me da error: "Indexer property 'lSoapClient.ClientProperty' has non-optional arguments which must be provided"

No se si voy por buen camino o estoy siendo un desastre.

Answer (score 2):

Mi error estaba en escribir:

`SoapClient.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = true;`

Cuando era:

`SoapClient.ClientProperty["ServerHTTPRequest"] = true;`